# deleting row from table throws syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to write a pop function for a sqlite project i have but for some reason I cannot delete a row. I can fetch everything in the row but when I try and delete I get an error.
this is how I am retrieving information:

```
elf.Cursor.execute(f"SELECT * from {table} ORDER BY ROWID LIMIT 1")
```

and this is how I am trying to delete:

```
self.Cursor.execute(f"DELETE from {table} ORDER BY ROWID LIMIT 1")
```

edit I tried changing the line to delete to this:

```
self.Cursor.execute(f"DELETE from {table} where ROWID = 1")
```

how ever I am unsure if the line I will be reading is the same I will be deleting.

when I try to delete I get the following:

> ```
> self.Cursor.execute(f"DELETE from {table} ORDER BY ROWID LIMIT 1")
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ORDER": syntax error
> ```

As far as I can tell I am following the example found here (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-delete/). can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the link of the example you follow:

> SQLite also provides an extension to the DELETE statement by adding
> ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses. **If you compile SQLite with the
> SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT compile-time option**, you can use the
> ORDER BY and LIMIT clause in the DELETE statement

So, the `ORDER BY`/`LMIT` clauses are not supported in a `DELETE` statement by SQLite, unless you make a custom version with the `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` compile-time option.

But you can do this:

```
DELETE from {table} WHERE ROWID = (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM {table})
```

The query that you tried:

```
DELETE from {table} where ROWID = 1
```

would work only if the min `ROWID` of the table is `1`, which is not always true.